# 分割して読み込んだファイルの結合でエラーがでる

Tags: python, python3, pandas

巨大なcsvファイルを扱うために分割してファイルを読み込んだのですが、その後の結合でエラーで出てしまいます。

**以下コード**

```
import pandas as pd
fname = '.../train.csv'
reader = pd.read_csv(fname, chunksize=10000)
df = pd.concat((r for r in reader), ignore_index=True)
```

**以下エラーメッセージ**

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

原因と対策を教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 適当なCSVファイルで試したところ、エラーにならずに正常終了しました。

Comment: 私も試しましたが正常終了しました。行数が少ないとかいう理由ではなさそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

コード自体には問題はなさそうなので、以下のようにして pandas のバージョンと行数を制限してcsvファイルがうまく読み込めているか調べてみてください。

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)
fname = '.../train.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fname, nrows=10000)
print(df.info())
print(df.head())
```

そして問題がなければ、次のようにコードを変えてみてエラーがでるかどうか確認すればいいと思います。エラーが発生する場合にはデバッグ用のコードを入れて、どこでエラーが発生しているか確認してください。

```
import pandas as pd
fname = '.../train.csv'
df = None
for r in pd.read_csv(fname, chunksize=10000):
    if df is None:
        df = r
    else:
        df = df.append(r, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: バージョンを確認しましたが、0.22で最新でした。10000行であれば読み込めました。ファイルサイズが７GBと大きいことが原因でしょうか？